# How do I load the system configuration data if it was stored in a file?

Tags: magento

I'm setting up a system configuration in the admin backend of magento, and it currently stores it the data in a file, and I wanted to have Magento grab the data from a file to show what the current value is. What method should I be overloading to achieve this? I thought it was the `load()` function after extending `Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data`, but that was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the System Configuration Data for your admin, you can try writing upgrade-scripts in your local module in the sql folder. Below is one example where I have set up the System Config Value for Avalanche.

```
    <?php
    $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $setup->startSetup();
    $setup->setConfigData('avalanche_config/avalanche_design/avalanche_customcss','1');
    $setup->endSetup();
```

Syntax and Usage of setConfig data

```
    ***setConfigData***
    access: public
    void setConfigData ( $path,  $value, [ $scope = 'default'], [ $scopeId = 0], [      $inherit = 0])
    $path
    $value
    $scope
    $scopeId
    $inherit
```

You can refer to http://codemagento.com/2011/02/install-scripts-and-upgrade-scripts/ for writing upgrade scripts.

This is one of the solution of setting up the System Config data, I am not sure if this works for you.
Anyway, good luck.

Swapna